# Can I tell if my chrome extension has been installed via inline install or the chrome store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When my extension is installed, is there a way to know if it was installed via inline install or installed from the chrome extension store?

I've looked through the Chrome Platform Apis and don't see anything obvious.

Comment: See [chrome.management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management), under `ExtensionInstallType`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [chrome.management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management):

For example:

```
chrome.management.getSelf(myInfo =>{console.log(myInfo.installType)})
```

According to the documentation, it will output:

> admin: The extension was installed because of an administrative policy,
>
> development: The extension was loaded unpacked in developer mode,
>
> normal: The extension was installed normally via a .crx file,
>
> sideload: The extension was installed by other software on the machine,
>
> other: The extension was installed by other means.

Besides, you can check manifest's `update_url` entry.

Comment: I saw this but I don't see anything here that will indicate an inline instillation vs an installation from the chrome store. Am I missing something?